# Slick Carousel Lazy Load content from embedded script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, slick.js

I'm trying to use the Slick Slider to progressively load the slideshow contents. I've found plenty of documentation that supports the loading of images, but I'm using this to slide between embedded info graphics built from infogr.am. I don't really have the best handle on JavaScript or jQuery. I am mainly wondering if this is possible, or if anyone has encountered a similar issue and managed to get it resolved.

Thanks in advance. If you need more information let me know and I can post more.

Comment: Is it a looping carousel? I assume you are using the infogr.am API, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using infogram, and no it does not loop. I'm using the slider syncing option to control the slideshow with infogr.am elements with another slideshow.